# Is it possible to permit multiple AWS CloudFront OAIs to access a single S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

I have some documentation which I wish to host on many websites, where each website is under a separate CloudFront distribution. Each of the CF distributions is in a separate AWS account, but all accounts fall under a single AWS Organization.

Ideally, I'd like to put that documentation into a single S3 bucket in one account and have all the CF distributions treat that bucket as an S3 origin (e.g. a behaviour would define accessing `/docs/*` to point to that single bucket). That means that the bucket would need to grant read permissions in its bucket policy to all of the OAIs (one OAI per CF distribution).

The ARN for an OAI looks like this: `arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2WJXXXXXXXXXX`.

Is it possible to define a policy which will sort of do what `aws:PrincipalOrgID` does for accounts (detailed here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/control-access-to-aws-resources-by-using-the-aws-organization-of-iam-principals/), but for CloudFront OAIs which are defined within those organization accounts?

EDIT:
I've tried adding a `Principal` of `*` and added `PrincipalOrgID` of my organization as per below but this didn't work.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject*",
        "s3:GetBucket*",
        "s3:List*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-myOrgId"
        }
}
```

Comment: Does a "normal" `aws:PrincipalOrgID` condition not work? Do you only want cloudfront to be able to access the bucket but not a normal user in your org?

Comment: No, I edited the question to show what I tried, but it didn't work. I want to be able to allow OAIs in other accounts to access the bucket. Not shown in the above are permissions for all the other org accounts to access the bucket too.

Comment: Do you have any follow-up? I'm struggling with the same issue right now :-(